# How to instruct `npm` to not download existing packages?

Tags: npm

Although it should be the responsibility of `npm` cli tool itself but since the logs indicate that it contacts the npm registry even for packages that are already present ... my question becomes:

> How do we avoid contacting npm registry for any packages that are already present in `node_modules` folder?

While I understand that it is part of the `npm` algorithm to create a complete clone by downloading all dependencies and then comparing them with the existing ones, it is way too inefficient for CI builds and I'm seeking advice or pointers to scritps that handle this better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [prefer-offline](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#prefer-offline) or [offline](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#offline) config of npm.

The second one (offline) will make installation fail if any new package will have to be downloaded from the registry. So if the package will not be found in the local cache.